# Convert VBA to Python script to cut column into smaller columns

Tags: python, excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am converting multiple Excel macro's (VBA) into one Python file using Spyder.
I have gotten to a VBA loop that I just don't really understand. To give you some idea of the parameters; NumRows is the value for the length of a column F, e.g. 1253
F is a column, or numpy array. G is the np.round(F,1) array of F.

```
' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      r = 1
      c = 12
      x = 2
      For x = 2 To NumRows - 2
      
        If Range("G" & x).Value > -10 Then
        Range("G" & x).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c))

            r = r + 1
        End If
        
         If Range("G" & x + 1).Value = 0 And Range("G" & x - 1).Value = 0 And Range("G" & x + 2).Value <> 0 Then
            c = c + 1
            r = 1
            
         End If
          
         Range("F" & x).Select
         Next x
         
    v = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 120
            
    Cells(i, 11).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = v
    v = v + 1
```

What the code basically is supposed to do, is to cut one column into multiple smaller columns at  the point where multiple zeros are found. Then, the new column starts only with one zero, followed by the row, until it finds a lot of zero values again.

So this --> this
[image: Column G]
[image: Multiple columns]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you think output is from source table? eg. The first three cells are `-0.4 -0.4 -0.3` in source table, but it doesn't show up in the output.

Comment: There are 70 numbers in the output table, but 41 numbers in the source table.

Comment: I understand that is not clear. I should have posted different columns. The -0.4 -0.4 -0.3 does show in the output, I it simply not included in the figure (possibly column A or B)